# CFset string concatenation (of query results)

Tags: coldfusion

Is it possible to set a ColdFusion variable to a concatenated string?

```
<cfoutput query="getName">
   <cfset myName=#Firstname# #Lastname#>
</cfoutput>
```

Doesn't seem to work, nor does

```
<cfoutput query="getName">
   <cfset teacherName=#Firstname# + #Lastname#>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really need an additional variable, ColdFusion's concatenation operator is `&`

```
 <cfset teacherName = Firstname &" "& Lastname>
```

Though for simple output, no extra variable is needed. Just output the column values:

```
<cfoutput query="getName">
   #Firstname# #Lastname# <br>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 4):

try using `<cfset teacherName= Firstname & " " &  Lastname>`

Comment: Edited to remove extraneous pound signs

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to using the ColdFusion `&` or `&=` [string operators](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09d55-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09d55-7ff8), you can also do the following:

```
<cfoutput query="getName">
    <cfset myName="#Firstname# #Lastname#">
    <p>#myName#</p>
</cfoutput>
```